# Short way of casting char codes contained in a byte array to int?

Tags: java, casting

There's a byte[4] containing char codes for random hex numbers, i.e. b[0] == 49, b[1] == 68, b[2] == 70 ...

I'd like to calculate something with these hex values, so I need to cast the char values to int. That sounds simple, but my solution looks terrible:

```
char c1 = ((char)b[0]);
String s1 = String.valueOf(c1);
int p1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

char c2 = ((char)b[1]);
String s2 = String.valueOf(c2);
int p2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);

...
```

Isn't there a shorter method? There's so many generic key words in my question that I can't find a solution through google either.

**Updated post:**

Whoops, I forgot to mention the byte[] contains hex values. So

```
int x = b[0] - '0';
```

won't suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
int p1 = b[0];
// etc
```

Oh, wait. You want to interpret the characters as digits and use the values. If you're sure that the byte values are ASCII digit codes, you can do this:

```
int p1 = b[0] - '0';
// etc
```

If you want a formally correct way to do it:

```
int p1 = Character.getNumericValue(b[0]);
// etc
```

This will correctly handle hex characters (0, 1, ..., F) and even things like `'\u216C'` (ROMAN NUMERAL FIFTY).

Comment: I think he wants 49 => 1 (not sure though).

Comment: @assylias - Yeah, I figured that out and updated my answer. It's too late at night for me to be answering SO questions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the array contains hex values, whoopsie. Is there a similarly short form for that, too? I checked the Character entry in the API and couldn't find a method that even mentioned the word "hex".

Comment: @Jake - I updated with a version that will handle that as well.

Comment: Oh excuse me, I should have tested that. I got confused with the C and ROMAN NUMERAL FIFTY, but it works with hex numbers, too. Thank you, that's the solution.